# What is the French equivalent of "you know"?

Tags: traduction, expressions-idiomatiques

What do the French say as a filler of confirmation that is equivalent to "you know" in the sense of "I don't know what to do, you know, I don't understand what's happening" or "There is a better way you know". Do they still say "tu sais/vous savez"?

Comment: I've linked to an already asked question that has your answer (and more)

Comment: [Please use caps for the language in English. Thanks.]

Answer (score 4):

We do say "Tu sais/vous savez", sometimes substituted by "Tu vois/vous voyez".

In an informal conversation context and in order to avoid two occurrences of the verb "savoir", I would however translate "I don't know what to do, you know, I don't understand what's happening" by "Je ne sais pas quoi faire, tu vois, je ne comprends pas ce qui se passe".

Comment: And often the use of "tu vois" sounds like "tu ahh", not far away from "tu as".

Answer (score 0):

*Évidemment* is a very common filler, especially on radio/TV.

Comment: Probably not the best choice here though...